# Fast Infoset decoder in Android

Tags: android, fastinfoset

I am implementing an Android web service client to consume a SOAP based web service. One of the output format is application/soap+fastinfoset, and I would like to take advantage of the data compression because of the relative high data rate.

Is there any Fast Infoset decoder for Android? I looked online for a long time, and could not find anything on this topic.

Thanks

... Alan

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to consider looking at W3C Efficient XML Interchange (EXI). It was adopted by W3C as the global standard and is far more compact than FastInfoset. You can find implementations for web-service and mobile platforms (including Android) from http://www.agiledelta.com.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only answer will really be to recompile the [reference implementation](http://java.net/projects/fi/sources/svn/show/trunk/code/fastinfoset/) to run on Android: there may be Xerces-J interface dependencies you'll need to work around.